# Manage provisioning profiles on my Mac OS Sierra build host

Tags: xcode, macos, provisioning-profile, macos-sierra, apple-configurator

I used to have an `iphone configuration utility` which is obsoleted on `Mac OS` after an upgrade to `Sierra`. It was replaced with `Apple Configurator` which is great for managing external devices but not for the Mac OS Host itself.

How can I manage installed provisioning profiles (delete some) on my Mac OS (Sierra) build host?

Answer (score 1):

I use [ProfilesManager](http://github.com/shaojiankui/ProfilesManager) now on High Sierra.